# Modelling Issues with IPMSM

Tags: matlab, simulink

Hi I am working on a model of an Interior Permanent Magnet Synchronous Machine (IPMSM) on simulink using the dynamic equations of the motor and creating a linear state space equation from them.

I have done the linearisation and have put it into simulink using the custom function blocks in the first picture on the twitter post.

[Twitter Pictures of Model and Syntax error](https://twitter.com/GreenardJack/status/527794531929165824)

My issue is that I have various variables such as R, Ld, Lq etc. I am quite new to simulink and I am after help, do I create a matlab file with these variables in with their values and how do I link that file to the variables in the equations.

I have attempted this in the past and I still get a message claiming a syntax error when I am certain that I am correct, the second twitter photo

I really need assistance on this, a step by step guide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Linking to a twitter picture of your problem is not the appropriate way to present it. You need to describe in the post itself what code isn't working and what the problem you're encountering is.

Answer (score 1):

The images are too low resolution to see anything. Still, if I understand your question correctly, the best way to define parameters used in a Simulink is to write a MATLAB script where those parameters are defined, and then call that script as part of the model callbacks, probably in `InitFcn`. For more details, please refer to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/model-callbacks.html).

Answer (score 1):

Create an m-file in the same folder as your model. Inside this file, you define the values of your parameters along with other initialization routines (I use clear all to delete all matlab variables stored in memory), for example:

```
clear all;
R = 0.31;
Ld = 0.155;
```

In your model, `File > Model Properties > Callbacks > InitFcn`, add the name of your m-file.

With this, when running the model, the m-file will be executed first, so your blocks containing `R` or `Ld` will get the corresponding values assigned.

Hope this helps.